# Java - Creating an image

Tags: java, image, graphics2d

I'm currently working on a game in Java and am trying to create a background without using any image files. The image consists of a square split into 4 triangles, each of which is a different color.

If anyone could point me towards some was of using `Graphics2D` and then saving it to a `BufferedImage`, that would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend:

- First create a BufferedImage using the constructor that takes three ints: a width, height, and a BufferedImage type, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB would probably work well, and the width and height will likely be constants in your program.
- You would extract a Graphics2D object out of the BufferedImage by calling its `createGraphics()` method.
- Then draw with the Graphics object using its `drawXXX(...)` methods of which you have many to select from.
- To change color, simply call `setColor(Color c)` on your Graphics/Graphics2D object.
- When done drawing, be sure to dispose of your Graphics object via its `dispose()` method.
- **Edit** as per Adrian Blackburn, check out the [BufferedImage Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawonimage.html) as part of the standard Oracle Java tutorials.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawonimage.html The java tutorial says the same thing

Comment: @AdrianBlackburn: thanks for the link -- and it probably says it a lot clearer than anything I can say! Edit: I've added your rec to my answer. Again, thanks for the link!

Comment: Beautiful answer, but I'd expect nothing less from you Hovercraft. Thanks a lot!